# Error installing mysql, any way to fix it?

Tags: mysql, debian

I was installing mysql with `apt-get install mysql-server` (like I always did) before that I had done an `apt-get update` (I am using Debian 6), and when I installed I found this problem, pretty common as I see, but I've followed all steps and nothing has worked.

I've tried with `apt-get install -f`
also with `apt-get remove mysql-server` (and `common`, and `mysql-server-5.1`) and also with `apt-get purge` (every package) and later `install`, but nothing...

I tried also

```
dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1
apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server
(all runed as Root)
```

Still, nothing worked, any idea???

```
130130 10:11:48  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.1 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports

    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:

mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.1; however:
Package mysql-server-5.1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
configured to not write apport reports
Errors were encountered while processing:
     mysql-server-5.1
     mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I tried

```
dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1


/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server-5.1 is broken or not fully installed
```

the case "Start" on /etc/init.d/mysql is

```
'start')
        sanity_checks;
        # Start daemon
        log_daemon_msg "Starting MySQL database server" "mysqld"
        if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn; then
           log_progress_msg "already running"
           log_end_msg 0
        else
            # Could be removed during boot
            test -e /var/run/mysqld || install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld

            # Start MySQL!
            /usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &

            # 6s was reported in #352070 to be too few when using ndbcluster
            for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14; do
                sleep 1
                if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn ; then break; fi
                log_progress_msg "."
            done
            if mysqld_status check_alive warn; then
                log_end_msg 0
                # Now start mysqlcheck or whatever the admin wants.
                output=$(/etc/mysql/debian-start)
                [ -n "$output" ] && log_action_msg "$output"
            else
                log_end_msg 1
                log_failure_msg "Please take a look at the syslog"
            fi
        fi
```

When I make mysql force-reload:

```
Reloading MySQL database server: mysqld/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
root@americandougnuts:/etc/init.d#
root@americandougnuts:/etc/init.d# Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

Comment: check the rights for /tmp and /var/tmp directories

Comment: When you ran `apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server`, did you get any error messages? If so, what? I'd go back and run that again to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason apt-get upgrade creates a new mysql bin file which doesn't have the correct ownership. This file is located in /var/lib/mysql. Because mysql can't access this file mysql can't start and the upgrade fails.

Check the file ownership of the files in /var/lib/mysql

ls -ltra /var/lib/mysql

---

```
-rw-rw----  1 mysql root        125 Oct 29 09:53 mysql-bin.000288
-rw-rw----  1 mysql root        125 Oct 29 09:53 mysql-bin.000289
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql       228 Oct 29 10:07 mysql-bin.index
-rw-rw----  1 root  root        125 Oct 29 10:07 mysql-bin.000291
-rw-rw----  1 root  root        125 Oct 29 10:07 mysql-bin.000290
```

---

Dirty workaround:

- open a second terminal
- while true; do chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/*; done
- in the original terminal
- apt-get upgrade -y

when the upgrade is successfully completed CRT+C the while loop in the second terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It says why it doesn't work in the output you shared:

```
Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

MySQL refuses to start, check MySQL's log files in `/var/log` to find out why, fix it and run `dpkg-reconfigure` again.

Comment: Thank you! the log is empty... also the logs on var/log/mysql

Comment: look at the init script how exactly mysql is started (hint: `bash -xv /etc/init.d/mysql start`) and try starting it manually in verbose/debug mode (see man manpage on how to do this).

Comment: Thank you, I checked the file, and I updated my comment, im going to start it on debug mode

Comment: I didnt find debug mode, but when I make force-reload it appears:
Reloading MySQL database server: mysqld/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
root@americandougnuts:/etc/init.d#
root@americandougnuts:/etc/init.d# Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

Answer (score 0):

run just "mysqld" in a shell as root to start mysql.  It should then print to the screen why it fails to start.  Often it an obsolete configuration option in /etc/mysql/my.cnf.

After you correct the error keeping mysql from starting, re-run `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1`